# PHP/HTML/CSS - If FireFox, If Chrome, If Safari

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there a simple conditional statement, css command, html, jquery, javascript or simple PHP dynamic way of detecting the current browser?

```
<!if firefox>
    .element { top:4px; }
<![endif]>
<!if chrome>
    .element { top:6px; }
<![endif]>
<!if ie>
    .element { top:8px; }
<![endif]>
<!if opera>
    .element { top:10px; }
<![endif]>
<!if safari_webkit>
    .element { top:12px; }
<![endif]>
```

Can this Psuedo code be done in jQuery/JS/HTML or CSS PHP etc?

Comment: Some useful info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css

Comment: I find it a bit... suspicious, to say the least, usage of four style rulesets instead of just two (one for IE8-, another for web browsers). Isn't the question about CSS3 (vendor-specific) rules, I wonder?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With CSS there is no way you can achieve browser detection.
However with PHP, ASP and other programming languages you can get browser detection within the page. I am not here to tell you the pro or cons about it - I take it you know about the bad and good about browser detection and web standards but here is the list.

### PHP solution.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
```

Then, compare it to what you want

For compare with, for example "firefox" you should do:

```
if(strlen(strstr($agent,"Firefox")) > 0 ){      
    $browser = 'firefox';
}
if($browser=='firefox'){
    echo '<style type="text/css">.element{top:2px}';
}
```

### jQuery solution.

```
// Safari CSS and Webkit Google Chrome
if ($.browser.webkit) {
   $("#element").css('top', '2px');
} else if ( $.browser.safari ) //not fully supported on 1.7 jQuery {
   $("#element").css('top', '2px');
// Opera CSS
} else if ( $.browser.opera ) {
   $("#element").css('top', '2px');
// Internet Explorer CSS
} else if ( $.browser.msie ) {
   $("#element").css('top', '2px');
// Mozilla FireFox CSS
} else if ( $.browser.mozilla ) {
   $("#element").css('top', '2px');
// Normal Revert, careful and note your the use of !important
} else {
   $("#element").css('top', '2px');
   // You can have normal JavaScript between these too
   document.getElementById("element").style.top="2px";
}
```

### Mootools solution.

```
if (Browser.ie){
    // This code will only run in IE
}

if (Browser.firefox2){
    // This code will only run in Firefox 2
}
if (Browser.firefox){
    // This code will only run in Firefox 
} 
if (Browser.chrome){
    // This code will only run in Chrome
} 
if (Browser.opera){
    // This code will only run in Chrome
}   
if (Browser.ie6 || Browser.ie7){
    // Please upgrade your browser
}
// Also notice you can use Engine.trident
if(Browser.Engine.trident) {

}
```

### Prototype solution.

```
if(Prototype.Browser.IE){
  // do something IE specific
}
if(Prototype.Browser.Opera){
  // do something Opera specific
}
if(Prototype.Browser.WebKit){
  // do something WebKit specific
}
if(Prototype.Browser.MobileSafari){
  // do something MobileSafari specific - iPhone etc
}
if(Prototype.Browser.Gecko){
  // do something Gecko specific
}
```

Comment: You could also use the Javascript variant: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: +1 for detail and approach. It works very well. At last a simple jQuery way to detect the current browser. Brilliant.

Comment: $.browser is deprecated since 1.3 and removed since 1.9
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: @Helto what is the new alternative as I cannot seem to find it?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid jQuery dropped support for this because it is unreliable. The solution is to just use straight up javascript, but keep in mind you can't count on it 100%. The consensus seems to be to look for features that you need instead of just browser name

This question has some good links on it referencing testing for features: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490452/using-javascript-to-detect-browser-type

To test features with jquery look at .support: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: I noticed support has gone. Is there an alternative. I would prefer to stick with existing library.

Answer (score 3):

To do this with CSS only.

You can target Firefox with this 'hack':

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {...}
```

And Chrome & Safari together like this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {...}
```

But not necessarily recommended...

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript:

```
navigator.appCodeName
```

Stores the browser codename:

```
navigator.appName
```

Is the name of the browser.

But I would recommend using jQuery for more efficiency and less headaches:

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
   $("#div ul li").css( "display","inline-table" );
} else if ( $.browser.msie ) {
   $("#div ul li").css( "display","inline" );
} else {
   $("#div ul li").css( "display","inline-table" );
}
```

**EDIT:** According to jQuery.com:

- webkit (Chrome and Safari)
- safari (deprecated)
- opera
- msie (Internet Explorer)
- mozilla (Firefox)

Source: [JQuery Site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: Can you show me a full sample of how to add css and html inside the elseif and all the elseif combinations, for example adjusting the top or left or margin property values

Answer (score 0):

In php you can use this code to detect browsers

```
<?php
  $msie = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'MSIE') ? true : false;
  $firefox = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Firefox') ? true : false;
  $safari = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Safari') ? true : false;
  $chrome = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Chrome') ? true : false;
?>
```