# Safari CSS placement issues

Tags: css, safari

Having a small issue getting my site to behave in safari.

Some specifics.

I am using safari for windows v5.1.7 but the issue is also present on ipad.

The issue i am having is the positioning of 1 element, which is only happening in safari, it is a small drop down so users can select currency, this is placed in my WP theme via the header.php.

The code i am using is

`<div class="currencytop" style="right: 85px; top: 6px; width: 9%;"><?php echo do_shortcode('[woocs]'); ?></div>`

I have had to style the code to get it to a position i was happy with and it looks OK in all browsers except safari.

You can see the offending element on my homepage here (top right on chrome but shifts under the social icons in safari) http://escapeandco.com/

Any help on correcting it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I would be more concerned about the dd-pointer-down icon that keeps moving around if you resize the window and the few elements that have id="undefined".

Comment: Not part of my question, but the pointer is a non issue as it is being removed. Any idea's on the safari issue??

Comment: if you remove all the right and top values that do nothing for you, just add "float:left" like all the other elements in the menu and it will look OK.

Comment: Many thanks Siderite worked perfectly (oddly i did try this but think i had some other issues that needed fixing first as they were interfering)

Answer (score -1):

you can detect browser and run different css for safari ,check out that link how to detect browser[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089942/php-html-css-if-firefox-if-chrome-if-safari).

Comment: let me see expert answer ,easy to mark down ,thnx that was only for suggestion. i think u need more  exercise.

Comment: This comment does not provide an answer to the question and has a link without description. His problem was not understanding the behavior of the element in Safari, not how to select various styles based on browser. Also, technically, your answer is plain wrong. Changing the CSS based on browser type might have worked a decade ago, when there were about three browsers in all, now it's just maintenance suicide.