# Detect the browser type using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using javascript to detect browser type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490452/using-javascript-to-detect-browser-type)
>   [Detect version of browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)

How to detect which type and version of browser does the User is using ?

I tried the following code, but it is not working.

```
var browserType = navigator.appName;
Alert(browserType);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Unless you're computing statistics this is probably the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Sorpigal, It is my requirement

Comment: Facts 1) google gives many answers 2) you shouldn't.

Comment: This isn't working because `Alert` is not defined ... use `alert` instead ... JavaScript is case-sensitive

Comment: @ManseUK, Exactly you are correct. I tried with small letter. It is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use small letter `a` instead of `A` in the `alert`.

```
var browserType = navigator.appName;
alert('the browser type is: ' + browserType);
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out the solution.

Comment: Your code gives the answer as `Netscape` when I tried in the `Chrome`.

Comment: @user1891768 It returns netscape for most browsers, Google 'window.navigator.appName netscape' - there are better ways to do what you're asking.

Comment: If I code as `navigator.appName` alone, it works perfectly in all the browser. Also, I edited your answer since the above code is working fine as I checked in all the browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
Alert(browserType);
```

with

```
alert(browserType);
```

javascript is case sensitive.

But :

- it's almost always wrong to try to detect the browser's type. [Prefer detection of features](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/)
- when we must, we usually explore (with regexes) `navigator.appVersion` or `navigator.userAgent` instead of `navigator.appName`.

For example :

```
 var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: see my comment in the question section....i already found out the solution with the help of ManseUK..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of browser using this code:

```
window.navigator.appCodeName
```

Comment: Your code gives the answer as `Mozilla` for all browsers.