# How to detect Firefox user agent?

Tags: browser, vbscript, asp-classic, user-agent

I am working on an application where I am required to make legacy code, which has been designed primarily for Internet Explorer, work with **Firefox**.

The problem I have hit is iframes nested within a table structure do not expand to the full height of the table cell. Due to the size of the web application the decision has been made to create a JavaScript shim to address this issue instead of making mark-up changes. This shim will only be included on the page if the browser is Firefox as the problem does not exist within other browsers I have tested.

So my question is:

`Using a classic ASP VBScript function how can I identify Firefox browsers, this should include any edge cases?`

So far I have the following which checks the user agent for the string value "Firefox". Are there any cases where this would not work?

```
function IsFirefox()

    dim userAgent : userAgent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
    dim locationOfFirefox : locationOfFirefox = InStr(1, userAgent, "Firefox", 1)

    IsFirefox = (locationOfFirefox > 0)

end function
```

Comment: Well, derived browsers won't work. You really want the rendering engine ID (Gecko), not the browser brand name.

Comment: do not try to identify the browser but the functions of a browser. i.e. the Internet Explorer 11 on a win 8.1 machine will give this user Agent string: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MDDRJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko" so when you look for "Gecko" to identify Firefox your script will fail

Comment: Your code is fine but risky. What if future build of Chrome will introduce this same bug/behavior? You realy better solve this client side, find workaround to the nested iframes e.g. use ordinary `<div>` elements and load their contents using simple jQuery `.load()` or `.get()` methods. These days `<iframes>` for internal pages are REALLY not needed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard unfortunately I am working on a legacy system which has `10246 iframes` found in `3589 files` so re-factoring the code to work without iframes is really not possible at this time.

Comment: @Jonathan you'll be surprised how powerful jQuery can be. You can convert all iframes to `<div>` elements with the same contents **at run time**. You won't have to touch single line of HTML code.

Comment: You might have the same issue with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490452/using-javascript-to-detect-browser-type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a document from the Mozilla Foundation, Firefox must be identified by the user agent when it **contains** the string *"Firefox/xyz"* **and does not contain** the string *"Seamonkey/xyz"*. More information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent